# Usage OrderBy in LINQ firstly the Cyrillic words then the Latin words

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
var listExample = new List<string>(){ "banana", "apple", "lemon", "orange", 
"cherry", "pear", "яблоко", "лимон", "груша", "банан", "апельсин", "вишня" };
listExample = listExample.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

The result is

```
{ "apple", "banana", "cherry", "lemon", "orange", "pear", "апельсин", "банан", "вишня", "груша", "лимон", "яблоко" }
```

But need first order by Russian then by English like this

```
{ "апельсин", "банан", "вишня", "груша", "лимон", "яблоко", "apple", "banana", "cherry", "lemon", "orange", "pear" }
```

How use OrderBy to get that result?

Comment: Do you only need this for LINQ to Objects (no EF etc)? How would you want to compare words that a part-Russian, part-English? (While "appleвишня" may not be a real word, it's certainly a valid string.)

Comment: Yes this need only for LINQ to Objects.
I don't understand where such words Like "appleвишня" should come from.

Comment: Your code *may* never need to deal with them - but what do you want it to do if it ever *does* see them? Which should come first, "appleвишня" or "вишняapple"? Once you've decided that, it should be relatively easy to implement.

Comment: You can provide your own `IComparer<TKey>` implementation to `OrderBy`

Comment: It is really nonstandard but very interesting case. The first should be "вишняapple".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Order checking if the work is `latin`.

The below code return the desired output where it's checking if the word is IsCyrillic.

```
    var listExample = new List<string>(){ "banana", "apple", "lemon", "orange",  "cherry", 
                           "pear", "яблоко", "лимон", "груша", "банан", "апельсин", "вишня" };

    var result = listExample.OrderBy(x => x)
                    .Select(x => new {val = x, isCyrillic = Regex.IsMatch(x, @"\p{IsCyrillic}")})
                    .OrderBy(x => !x.isCyrillic).Select(x => x.val);

    foreach (var str in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
```

Check the full code at this fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/9o4FJt

The output of above program is

> апельсин
>   банан
>   вишня
>   груша
>   лимон
>   яблоко
>   apple
>   banana
>   cherry
>   lemon
>   orange
>   pear

Answer (score 1):

For a fairly "quick and dirty" approach I'd probably order by "the first index containing a Cyrillic character" (using `int.MaxValue` for "no Cyrillic") followed by regular ordering (which allows you to make it case-insensitive etc).

So something like:

```
var result = list.OrderBy(GetFirstCyrillicIndex).ThenBy(x => x).ToList();
...

private static int GetFirstCyrillicIndex(string text)
{
    // This could be written using LINQ, but it's probably simpler this way.
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] >= 0x400 && text[i] <= 0x4ff)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return int.MaxValue;
}
```

Complete example including my awkward words:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<string> { 
            "banana", "apple", "lemon", "orange", 
            "cherry", "pear", "яблоко", "лимон",
            "груша", "банан", "апельсин", "вишня",
            "appleвишня", "вишняapple"
        };
        var result = list.OrderBy(GetFirstCyrillicIndex).ThenBy(x => x).ToList();
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    private static int GetFirstCyrillicIndex(string text)
    {
        // This could be written using LINQ, but it's probably simpler this way.
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (text[i] >= 0x400 && text[i] <= 0x4ff)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return int.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
апельсин
банан
вишня
вишняapple
груша
лимон
яблоко
appleвишня
apple
banana
cherry
lemon
orange
pear
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of alternative, if you don't want to implement a whole new custom order method, you can create your extension method and use existing order methods:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
     public static IEnumerable<string> OrderByCyrillicFirst(this IEnumerable<string> list)
     {
         var cyrillicOrderedList = list.Where(l => string.IsNullOrEmpty(l) ? false : IsCyrillic(l[0])).OrderBy(l => l);
         var latinOrderedList = list.Where(l => string.IsNullOrEmpty(l) ? true : !IsCyrillic(l[0])).OrderBy(l => l);
         return cyrillicOrderedList.Concat(latinOrderedList);
     }

     public static IEnumerable<string> OrderByCyrillicFirstDescending(this IEnumerable<string> list)
     {
         var cyrillicOrderedList = list.Where(l => string.IsNullOrEmpty(l) ? false : IsCyrillic(l[0])).OrderByDescending(l => l);
         var latinOrderedList = list.Where(l => string.IsNullOrEmpty(l) ? true : !IsCyrillic(l[0])).OrderByDescending(l => l);
         return cyrillicOrderedList.Concat(latinOrderedList);
     }

    //cyrillic symbols start with code 1024 and end with 1273.
    private static bool IsCyrillic(char ch) =>
        ch >= 1024 && ch <= 1273;       
}
```

and usage:

```
var listExample = new List<string>(){ "banana", "apple", "lemon", "orange", "cherry", "pear", "яблоко", "лимон", "груша", "банан", "апельсин", "вишня" };

var result = listExample.OrderByCyrillicFirst();
```

output:

> апельсин банан вишня груша лимон яблоко apple banana cherry lemon orange pear

References: **[DotNetFiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JaB35P)**, **[Cyrillic Unicode Chart](http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/languages/europe/cyrillic/cyrillicchart/)**